# UWP "Start New Instance" Closes Old Instance

Tags: c#, uwp, multiple-instances

I'm trying to find a way to run my UWP application multiple times on my computer with debug. When I try to use "Start New Instance" to do so, the old instance just closes and I end up with still just one instance of my program. I don't get any kind of message or anything, it just closes. My setup for running the application is "Debug x86". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: UWP apps are single-instance by definition today. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There may be another way to do it.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I have an application that takes angle measurements from a sensor and outputs them to the debug console. I'd like to take measurements from two sensors at once if possible, hence needing to run two instance of my application.

Comment: If you need exactly 2 instances of your app (as opposed to an arbitrary number of instances), you could add a second <Application/> node in your appxmanifest pointing to the same EXE/entrypoint. This way you can launch and debug two separate instances of your app, each in its own process. If this is what you are looking for, I can write up a proper response (was planning to write a related blog post at some point as well).

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT This is exactly what I'm looking for Stefan! It would be great if you could write up a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test and debug two instances of your app separately (in different processes) you can add a second  node to your manifest. The Visual Studio IDE doesn’t have support for multiple  nodes today, so you will have to do it manually – here are the steps:

1) Open the UWP app project in VS

2) Deploy and run to make sure it works

3) Go to the APPX layout folder, i.e. $(OutDir)APPX

4) Edit the appxmanifest.xml to clone the Application node

5) Change “ID”, “DisplayName”, “Description” to keep the instances apart

6) Increase the version number in the manifest

7) In a powershell prompt navigate to $(OutDir)APPX

8) Run “add-appxpackage -register appxmanifest.xml”

Now you have two instances of your app in the app list and you can launch/test/debug them independently, in separate processes.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I really appreciate your response. I tried following your instructions and am getting the following error on Step 8:

Comment: -- "add-appxpackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFB, The provided package is already installed, and reinstallation of the package was blocked. Check the AppXDeployment-Server event log for details.
Windows cannot register package 5c8ac0fd-b3a0-49bb-ad66-da893725e41b because it is in development mode and the package
is already installed. Increment the version number of the package to be registered, or remove the old package for
every user on the system before registering this package.

Comment: I thought that I did. I incremented the version at the very top of the XAML doc. Which "version" within the file am I suppose to increment, and does it matter in which way I increment it?

Comment: Increment the version number in the "Identity" object of the appxmanifest. You need to increment at least the 3rd digit, i.e. from 1.0.0.0 go to 1.0.1.0.

Comment: Thank you. As you can probably tell I'm a novice in VS App Development. After the 8 steps are completed, how do I run the app in separate processes?

Comment: After completing step 8 go to your system's app list. You should see two separate entries for your app. Each one will launch in a different process.